# 3 positional arguments expected by 'runAI', but 2 found

Tags: flutter, dart, brain-fusion

this is my image_cubit.dart
[image]

if i add third positional argument resolution resolution in the above then i will get error at home_page.dart at this line

[image]

[image]

pls help me if anyone can help

i want anyone that can help me in resolving my error

Comment: add images like this so the reader don't have to go to another page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [source code](https://github.com/dj-yacine-flutter/brain_fusion/blob/master/lib/src/data/ai.dart) of the library, you will see that the method runAI requires three arguments:

```
Future<Uint8List> runAI(
    String query,
    AIStyle style,
    Resolution resolution,
  )
```

so you need to pass in a **Resolution** object in your method call.

I.E.

```
Uint8List image = await _ai.runAI(
      query,
      AIStyle.sovietCartoon,
      Resolution.r1x1,
    );
```

Comment: thanku you so much

Comment: how i can connect with you i am facing 2 more problems also

Comment: @DunaCruickshank - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such so other people can find it more easily.